How does vcpkg detect compiler?
I installed multiple versions of Visual Studio. When I open a developer command prompt from the latest Visual Studio and run vcpkg to install a package, it shows an older version of compiler(belong to an older version of Visual Studio) found. I check the environment variables of the command prompt but do not find variables/directories referring to the old version of Visual Studio. I wonder why vcpkg detects the older version of compiler.

What version of CMake do you have installed on your system?

Try creating a basic CMake project yourself. Just a minimal one and see what compiler your basic project chooses. Please update the posts with the results from that tiny experiment. Otherwise there isn't enough information to help.

@jpr42 thanks. After I upgrade VS, the problem disappears.
